# background image interpolation with caryopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

Recently I updated to matplotlib 3.3.1 on python 3.8. I use cartopy version 0.18.0. With this version, the background image interpolation seems to work anymore. Does anyone have a workaround/soultion?
Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.crs.PlateCarree()))
ax.set_extent([67, 75, 20, 26])
ax.add_image(cimgt.GoogleTiles(), 8, interpolation='spline36')
```

Which throws an error:

> TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'interpolation'

Comment: What is your desired outcome? What version of `cartopy` supported the 'interpolation' argument to `cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.add_image`? `add_image` currently does not allow any args or kwargs https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/blob/4069ad818d5fe948c1eac7d1cbe81b9425eca491/lib/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py#L422

Comment: I was using same verison of cartopy, but with matplotlib 3.1 on python 3.6. I need interpolation for better looking map. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155110/why-do-my-google-tiles-look-poor-in-a-cartopy-map

Answer (score 0):

If you need better resolution images, you need to increase the `scale` value. In your code, you can change 8 to 10 as a new experiment.

```
ax.add_image(cimgt.GoogleTiles(), 10)
```

**Edit1**

Since the use of projection (`crs.PlateCarree()`) different from the original (`crs.Mercator()`) causes the image's reprojection at the time of rendering, and results in unsatisfactory image quality. And this type of images, with sharp edges/lines, symbols, and texts, are difficult to get a good result from reprojection or interpolation. Let's use the original projection to plot the map and investigate the result.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

tiles = cimgt.GoogleTiles()
image_crs = tiles.crs

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,12), subplot_kw=dict(projection=image_crs))

ax.set_extent([67, 75, 20, 26], crs=ccrs.crs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_image(cimgt.GoogleTiles(), 8)
plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image: rajkot]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However, the scale parameter just adds more details, but the map quality does not improve. Please see the discussion at https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1048

Comment: @VinodKumar Is the new approach gives better image quality?

Comment: This indeed improves image quality, but I would prefer not to skip projection (crs.PlateCarree()).  This is required for adding further data overlays on the map.

Comment: If other data overlays are vector, no problem on web-mercator projection. Only certain types of raster data will fails when reprojected.